# How can the contents of an installed file marked Permanent="No" be preserved during an upgrade?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Installers of previous versions of our software include a Component File that was *NOT* marked with `Permanent="Yes"`. Now, we wish to read the pre-upgrade contents of this file during the upgrade process, which will overwrite the file with different contents. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you said exactly what you were doing that would cause the file to be overwritten. Some major upgrades (is that what you're doing?) will do a complete uninstall of the product first, followed by a complete install of the newer product. If that's the situation then use a custom action sequenced before RemoveExistingProducts to back up the file somewhere so that your application can retrieve the content, or get the content you need before it's ovewritten.

If you are doing a major upgrade sequenced later (such as afterInstallExecute) or you are doing a patch then it is by no means certain that the file will be overwritten because file overwrite rules will not replace a file that has been updated since it was installed. If the application altered the file then this type of upgrade will not overwrite it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370531(v=vs.85).aspx

Or in the case that the file is unchanged since it was installed, change the dates so it appears to be modified, as described here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2013/05/23/updating-the-last-modified-time-to-prevent-windows-installer-from-updating-an-unversioned-file/

It's also not clear that Permanent=yes is what you want anyway - that would glue the file to the system forever. You may be thinking of NeverOverwrite, but it's typically not required if the app changes the files, and easier to decide at upgrade time (by changing dates) instead of committing to NeverOverwrite when it's sometimes unclear what the product may need in the future.

A comment refers to retrieving the previous version of the product during the upgrade. There are a number of ways to do this:

If you know the ProductCode of the previous version, MsiGetProductInfo (and equivalents in script etc) will return product version values or strings:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370130(v=vs.85).aspx

Or if you'd rather not hardcode the value, MsiEnumProducts passing the UpgradeCode will return a list of installed ProductCodes. This technique is most useful if you have your own bootstrapper or UI where you want to show the user the current installed version.

In a WiX major upgrade the associated property (WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED) is a list of the ProductCodes detected (usually a list of one) so you can use that to get the version of the product being upgraded. In a small vbscript example, something like:

set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")

and:

prodversionstring = installer.productinfo(WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED, "VersionString")

will get you close.

Comment: We are only doing major upgrades. The file I would like to preserve contains the current version number.  We drop this file on install because our users can upgrade to any future version.  During an upgrade, we would like to know the version being upgraded from for configuration merging.

Users with already installed versions cannot start with a clean install, they can only be upgraded.  Can we only use RemoveExistingProducts in new versions of the installer to preserve files?

Alternatively, do you know a good way to get the previous version information from the OS during upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this file is a configuration file such as an XML file, I find this is just a tough area of Windows Installer.   You ship file version 1,  the end user modifies certain attributes and then you ship file version 2 to which you want to preserve those customizations.

The problem is this is a very complex merge. It works somewhat OK if you only care about 1-2 attributes but if the answer is  I need to preserve all of it then you are stuck between losing all the customizations or not getting the changes from version 2 of the file.

You could write extensive custom actions to do all this during the installer but I propose there is a better way:  Have 2 files.

1 file that is owned by the installer and can always be safely overwritten and 1 file that is owned by the application that overrides are stored in.  Think of it like a transformation file.   The installer doesn't know about this file so it never overwrites or deletes it.  (The very definition of user data from an MSI perspective.)

For example the .NET framework Web.Config schema  [AppSettings element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903313(v=vs.71).aspx) has a file attribute that was designed to support this nicely.

> Specifies a relative path to an external file containing custom
>   application configuration settings. The specified file contains the
>   same kind of settings that are specified in the , , and
>    elements and uses the same key/value pair format as those
>   elements.  The path specified is relative to the main configuration
>   file. For a Windows Forms application, this would be the binary folder
>   (such as /bin/debug), not the location of the application
>   configuration file. For Web Forms applications, the path is relative
>   to the application root, where the web.config file is located.
>
> Note that the runtime ignores the attribute if the specified file can
>   not be found.